# Dynamically change used database table while django app is running?

Tags: python, django

I want to create a service that has a page to configure a data base table (columns and types) and that allows to CRUD lines in it via the page.

The content of that table should then be used for comparison with payload of rest api call.

I am quite new to django and don't know if that approach is possible with the django ORM. What I saw so far is that one defines the database scheme hardcoded and I didn't see how I can make my concept running with this.

If not I am thinking about representing and managing this dynamically created table via a json or likewise object that is stored in an object database.

Comment: If you don't need the ORM but can work with just SQL queries, there's no issue here. Using the ORM like this would maybe bea bit of a stretch...

Comment: It is possible, whether advisable is a different story.

Comment: I actually find the idea of using the ORM appealing, because I assume it makes a lot of things easier in testing. If it's possible can you give some hint how? If you consider it a really bad idea, would you advise to go the way to represent that table via a json instead?